# Action opening DWG file in Intellicad using file name in a attribute table

Tags: qgis, actions

I have tried numerous variations in creating an action to open a DWG file in Intellicad after selecting a specific row in a table in QGIS.

I am quite frankly stumped at this point.

I have the DWG files associated with Intellicad, and can open them directly from Explorer.

I am trying to create a project management system in QGIS that will allow me to retrieve specific projects based upon various fields within the data table.

I have the folder location and name of the file I wish to open, as well as other pertinent information.

I highlight the row/field of the project I desire, right click, then Highlight the Open MSCAD file option in the dropdown menu.

[image]

I then click on that option and get the following error.

[image]

As I stated above, I have tried numerous options when trying to configure the actions including full file path and file extension for the executable, as well as other variations.

This is the actions page of the current properties for that layer.

[image]

Any suggestions?

QGIS 2.18.17 64 Bit, Windows 7

Comment: Is ICAD in PATH?  E.g if you open cmd and then type ICAD what do you get?

Comment: Nathan,
I checked the PATH, as I had upgraded to a newer version of ICAD, I did update the path to the newest version, and ICAD does execute from the command line, but I still get the error from trying to open it within QGIS. I have also gone through the other various action types to see if any of them would work. I also added the full file path for ICAD explicitly, but still nothing.

Comment: Might need to quote you arguments to ICAD in the actions

Comment: `ICAD '[% RT_FOLDER %]'` etc

Comment: Nathan,
I have tried just about every combination of quotes, double quotes, and every other option available that I feel may be viable, but I still get the error message. So now, I am going to try and shorten the file paths, and file names to see if their current length may be the issue.

I also checked to see if there may be a memory issue, but I have run both QGIS and ICAD simultaneously on numerous occasions.

I am able to start ICAD from the command line, open the files using Explorer, and start ICAD from the desktop, while QGIS is running, so memory is not the issue.

Comment: Show me the full command you are using.

Comment: Nathan

The following is the last version of the command I tried.

ICAD "[%"RT_Folder" + "Cad_File"%]"

I have tried the same with single quotes.

I have also just tried to execute ICAD with out any parameters for the action.